# How can I have android reinstall my installed apps after I do a factory reset?

Tags: applications, google-play-store, restore, factory-reset

I have a nexus one and I installed a bunch of apps on it.

After I do a 'factory reset', I go back to 'Android Market' and I see it is trying to download the apps I installed before. However, all of them are stuck in 'Downloading...' - they do not get installed.

I am on WiFi, so it is not an network issue.

Any idea how to re-install those apps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes the market gets "hung up" on some of the app downloads. You can long press the item in question that is stuck and then cancel the download.  You'll have to re-start the download yourself, but this will usually fix the problem.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to Bryan's answer, you could try going to `Settings -> Applications -> Manage applications` and clearing the data for the Market.  That might be easier than manually cancelling every download.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this answer:

https://android.stackexchange.com/a/147872/2960

This I think solves exactly your problem.