# How to resume app restore after stopping it on first opening Google Play?

Tags: google-play-store, restore

I've installed a fresh stock ROM from Google site on my Galaxy Nexus.

At the time I've opened the Google Play and started installing the 157 apps... the problem is that I needed to stop downloading in the middle as I needed to move to an area without wifi coverage, so I pressed stop.

Now I don't see any option to resume that installation.

Is it really a one shot? How could I have paused it to avoid downloading it on 3G?

Comment: I think it's "one shot." I am willing to be proven wrong though. I have faced this a few times.

Comment: This should be a feature request, I'm in the same pickle you were!

Comment: It seems by the latest answer that it isn't. At least if you're willing to use shell commands.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Use [`bmgr`](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/bmgr.html) from `adb shell`. See [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/49425/114824) for a complete explanation of backup sets.

Root access is ***not required***.

```
shell@maguro:/ $ bmgr list sets
  1234567890abcdef : droid48
  34567890abcdef12 : galaxy49
  ...

shell@maguro:/ $ bmgr restore 1234567890abcdef
Scheduling restore: droid48
done
```

This triggered a full restore of all the previously installed apps on my device instantly.

Comment: Awesome, great tip. Does this work on every Android version?

Comment: @NeTeInStEiN This was on 5.1. Per documentation: bmgr runs on devices supporting API Level 8 or greater.

Comment: Useful tip. This work on my Note 7 replacement. I interrupted my app/settings restoration while trying to simultaneously connect to my cellular provider. The phone prompted me to restart. I restarted, assuming that the restoration would resume. After it didn't, I went online and found this tip. This resumed my app downloads. FYI: My Note 7 didn't automagically appear in `adb devices`. I followed this guide to uninstall default drivers and install "Koush" "Universal Windows ADB Driver": http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/android-wont-connect-windows-adb-fix-it-three-steps/

Comment: I just tried this on a variant of 7.1 (from lineageos) and it did require root, when run from a terminal emulator (vs abd).  But it worked terrifically to get things started again.

Comment: fantastic tip. This worked great to get me set backup even after interrupting a restore to root/configure. thanks!

Comment: *Love* this, just a shame you can't choose which apps like you can in the original setup.

Comment: Just wanted to say Thanks, this is about the 5th time I've found this note and used it.  Just did it via adb (without root) on the Pixel 2 XL, so it still works on 8.0.

Comment: I've got several consecutive identical backup sets. Anyway to tell which is which?

Comment: I got "No restore sets"

Answer (score 8):

There's no option to resume. If you stop you can only manual download later.

If you didn't pressed stop, **you could just disable data transfer and, when connected again, download will continue**.

If you stop, the current sync state will be sent to the server and it will be (without the apps that weren't installed) stored as the device final state after restore.

And by the way, clear market data will not help (Tested >5 times on reflash my Desire)

Comment: At the time I though there must be a way to resume or restart it later...

Comment: Market store device state, so if stop with internet disabled and then clear market data before connect - restore can be restarted (no guarantee). If you stop with internet enabled - new device state will be saved, and next time restore will proceed to curent state (until you change it installing new apps).

Comment: "Market store device state" by this you are refering to store online the device state right?

Answer (score 2):

If you had turned off 3G, or even the device altogether, the downloads would have 'paused' so to say, and would have been resumed as soon as a data connection became available.

Apart from that, there is no way to pause an app download from Google Play, to resume later.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem. Don't know exactly what I did but I removed the Google account from my phone and re-signed in. Then I opened the Play Store and all my previous apps began downloading. Hope this helps

Comment: A side note to consider: On pre-ICS devices (Android 2.x), removing the Google account also removes data connected to Google Apps (such as accounts, calendar-data, etc.) from the device. While this shouldn't be a big deal for data already synced, I'm not sure concerning settings (unsynced data of course would be lost). No problem, though, starting with Android 4.0 – and yes, dropping and re-adding the account should trigger restore when you check the backup option on add.

Answer (score 0):

A similar problem happened with me and I try to factor reset a few times. It did not work. What worked was as follows:

1. Factor reset the phone.
2. After setting the language, the phone will ask you to connect to wifi. While connecting with wifi, go to top taskbar, swipe data, and disable mobile data.
3. Once the wifi is connected go through the process and while selecting the reset, if there is more than a day old (not today's) backup is available use that. You may loose one or two days worth of data, sms etc but mostly other stuff will be recovered. It will also save you the trouble of going through installing each app separately.